# Call Action from kendo ui datepicker event in asp.net mvc 4, using razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

-Hi, I have a kendo UI datepicker in my Index view, and I want to call the Index action again when I select some date, sending this date as a parameter to the Index action, but I don't know how to start, don't know if I need to declare a web method to be called from java script or not, any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your index action doing? Would you be calling an overloaded version of your action?

Comment: No, it has an optional argument, it is declared like this:
`public ActionResult Index(DateTime? date = null)`

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
                        change: function(){
                            var selectedDate = this.value();
                            var url ='@Url.Action("yourAction","yourController")';
                            url += "?date=" + selectedDate;
                            document.location.href = url;
                        }                           
                    });
```

this will send selected date to you'r controller action.hope this could help.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I'd like the Action to be called when I pick the date, without having to press 'Enter' or something, I don't know if there's another event for doing this.

Comment: You would have to identify the DOM element and register an onclick event with js. JQuery would work quite well for this.

Comment: And what if i give an invalid input first????Nothing will happen and the change event doesnot triggered...